# Inner div 100% width of parent div exceeds bounds

Tags: css, html

My inner `#div_mainPanel` is 100% width, but if you look at the right-bottom corner it's over the parent div. I have tried removing `width: 100` from the inner div and the width problem is solved, but not height.

Why does it display outside of the parent div if I have set width to 100% and margin/padding is set to 0px?

Thanks in advance

```css
#div_mainContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#div_mainPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_mainContainer">
  <div id="div_mainPanel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Borders count for sizing calculations. Your inner div picks up 100% of the height/width of the parent, so it becomes 500x300, but then adds 2px all around for the border, so it's really 502x302 and leaks over the parent's border on the right/bottom edges.

Comment: One minor observation: If it adds 2px border all around, size becomes 504x304. :)

Answer (score 12):

This is correct behaviour. The inner div is set to 100% width of the parent, but this does not include the border on it, so it is 100% + 2px.

To prevent the inner div being displayed outside the bounds of the parent, add `box-sizing: border-box` to both the parent and the child:

```css
#div_mainContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div_mainPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_mainContainer">
  <div id="div_mainPanel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is now a much better way to solve this problem: use `border-box` sizing for your CSS:

http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Now `100%` will be a much more natural way to set sizes of child elements.

Answer (score 0):

thats because the border attribute goes over the 100%... same as the padding value.

thats why its 2px out.

Answer (score 0):

The border property is not calculated in the width of the box either. So your box is actually being calculated as 100% + 2px for the border. For the width, just remove the `width: 100%` because a division (block-level element) will already expand to fill the width of the container automatically, better than a 100% width can do (because it will consider padding, border, and margin).

If you're always using an exact height on the parent container, why not just use an exact height of 498px on the child, which will calculate to a total height of 500px for the child.